# Is there any c++ tcp server on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, tcpserver

I want to develop one no-blocking tcp server with c++, is there any open source project like Twisted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) is discussed quite frequently in the [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio) tag on SO. Copying from the tag wiki that I wrote:

> Most programs interact with the
>   outside world in some way, whether it
>   be via a file, a network, a serial
>   cable, or the console. Sometimes, as
>   is the case with networking,
>   individual I/O operations can take a
>   long time to complete. This poses
>   particular challenges to application
>   development. The Boost.Asio library is
>   intended for programmers using C++ for
>   systems programming, where access to
>   operating system functionality such as
>   networking is often require

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.com) which has several interfaces, including C++.

It does more that just a socket tcp server, but that is part of the appeal. It is licensed under the very liberal LGPL with optional commercial support.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) Toolkit. Especially the Reactor and event demultiplexing and event handler dispatching support. The license is very easy and is similar to the BSD License